# processComplete == 2 error. mySQL Backup Java

Tags: java, backup, mysql, database-restore

I keep getting 'processComplete == 2' error. I am sure someone here will spot my error in seconds.

Here is my code...
    String filePath = "F:/backup";
    File f1 = new File(filePath);
    f1.mkdir();

```
String bath = "F:/backup" + "/backup.sql";
String executeCmd = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump -u" + username + " -p" + password + " --database " + host + " -r " + bath;

Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

if (processComplete == 0){
    System.out.println("Backup complete");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Backup failure");
}
```

I tried debugging in Java. So far everything up to the int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor(); line is correct. However, from the 'if (processComplete == 0){' bit it jumps straight to

```
else{
    System.out.println("Backup failure");
}
```

I keep getting 'processComplete == 2' error and I would, and I mean greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me where I am going wrong. It creates a backup directory successfully but not a backup.sql file.

Comment: If you have any 'select into' statements in the sql file, it could be that the statement isn't returning any data. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3846037/862441. Exit code of '2' indicates 'not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySql 5.6 documentation I looked up, the user and password parameters are both of the form -word=value, and you only have them as -lvalue (where l is a letter).  Yours might be an allowed substitute, but it seems worth it to try it the way they give in the documentation, "-user=whoever -password=password".

Since you're on windows, it seems reasonable to format the string for the command on the F drive with windows directory separators instead of unix/mac ones.  So I would try using "f:\\backup", etc., instead of what you have there.

As a debugging tool, you might try writing the command out to a file, then copying and pasting it into a DOS window and running it.  Don't cheat yourself -- don't type in ANYTHING, take it all from the program.  At least that way you can look at the output.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean restoreDB(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String source) {
    String executeCmd = "mysql" + " --user=" + dbUserName+ " --password=" + dbPassword+ " " +dbName+ " < "+ source;
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {
        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Database created successfully.");
            return true;
        }
        else if(processComplete == 1) {
            System.out.println("Unknown database: " + dbName);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Could not restore the database.");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you have changed?